# Módulo NodeJS executando antes do EventListener

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou criando um módulo para `node` e ao realizar alguns testes com o `eventListener` do tipo `change` em um campo do tipo `file`, o módulo é executado antes de um arquvo ser inserido no campo.

```
exports.preview = (fileInput, whereToSee) => {
    if (fileInput && fileInput[0]) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event) => {
            whereToSee.attr('src', event.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput[0]);
     } else {
        console.error('None!!'); // Mensagem de teste
    }
```

}

O Código de teste:

```
var upload = require('../index.js');

const file = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

file.addEventListener('change', upload.preview(this, document.querySelector('#blah')));
```

Logo quando abro o navegador  a mensagem `None!!` é exibida, ou seja, o event `change` esta sendo ativado antes mesmo de um arquivo ser selecionado.

Estou utilizando o `webpack` para criar o `bundle.js` apartir do arquivo `main.js` que é o arquivo onde encontram-se os códigos de teste:

> webpack main.js bundle.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de usar o conceito de *high order function*, ou seja retornar uma função para o `.addEventListener` chamar, uma callback neste caso.

Poderia ser assim:

```
exports.preview = (fileInput, whereToSee) => {
    return function(){
        if (fileInput && fileInput[0]) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (event) => {
                whereToSee.attr('src', event.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput[0]);
         } else {
            console.error('None!!'); // Mensagem de teste
        }
    }
}
```

dessa maneira quando invocas a função como tens no teu código, como argumento do `addEventListener`, ela captura as variáveis no escopo da callback que retornas. Essa sim (a callback)  será chamada quando houver `change`.

Comment: mas isso não é o mesmo que atribuir uma função ao `exports` ?

Comment: @RafaelAcioly não. Precisas de passar uma função ao exports como tens, e essa função retorna outra, que é a callback que vai ser usada. Pois o `addEventListener` precisa de uma função, e como tens ela é executada, o `if` corre e o `addEventListener` não recebe nem sequer uma função/callback nos argumentos.

Comment: isso resolveu! obrigado! mas agora estou tendo outro problema também! rs quando passo o `this` como parametro de `upload.preview(this, ...)` o objeto de file input não é retornado, e sim um objeto (não sei qual exatamente), como poderia para passar o proprio `file` como parametro sem ter que seleciona-lo novamente?

Comment: @RafaelAcioly não seria caso de passar `file` em vêz de `this`?

Comment: mas eu preciso pegar o element depois que ele for alterado `change`, se eu passar o `file` o elemento ainda esta vazio.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly mas ele é mantido, só por ele receber um novo valor/ficheiro não perdes a referência. Quando o `change` fôr chamado, o `input` terá mudado e podes ler o que precisas dele.